# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D437D437" under radix 16

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

```
String d="0xD437D437";
System.out.println(Integer.decode(d));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs state

> This sequence of characters must represent a positive value or a NumberFormatException will be thrown.

But `0xD437D437` *is* a negative value, namely `-734538697`, as can be seen by `Integer.toHexString(-734538697)` resulting in `"d437d437"`.

Therefore either parse it as a `Long` as @Bonniu says if you are looking for a positive value or if you are actually trying to parse a negative int you could just convert the resulting `Long` back into an `Integer` / `int`:

```
Long.decode("0xD437D437").intValue() // -734538697
```

Answer (score 2):

Your number is too big to fit in integer type - `0x7FFFFFFF` in hex is the largest number (2147483647 = 2^31-1). If you want to use this String as a number, use `Long.decode(d)` to get it as Long.

```
String d = "0x7FFFFFFF";
String e = "0x80000000";
String f = "0xD437D437";
System.out.println(Integer.decode(d));
System.out.println(Long.decode(e));
System.out.println(Long.decode(f));
```

will print

```
2147483647
2147483648
3560428599
```